# Redis sentinel can not fail over the slave service

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel

I'm gonna deploy a simple master-slave redis cluster with two servers: `192.168.0.101, 192.168.0.103`, and 101 is the master.

here is the `sentinel.conf` on 103 server:

```
port 26379

bind 192.168.0.103 127.0.0.1

sentinel myid 49f552d5540fdcb8aa60be25208c56b689d3c0b0
sentinel monitor mymaster 192.168.0.101 6379 2
sentinel down-after-milliseconds mymaster 60000
sentinel failover-timeout mymaster 900000

sentinel auth-pass mymaster arsenal

sentinel config-epoch mymaster 0

# Generated by CONFIG REWRITE
dir "/etc/redis"
sentinel leader-epoch mymaster 3
sentinel known-slave mymaster 192.168.0.103 6379

sentinel current-epoch 3
```

and my redis.conf on 103 server:

```
bind 127.0.0.1 ::1
protected-mode yes
port 6379
tcp-backlog 511
timeout 0
daemonize yes
supervised no

dbfilename dump.rdb
dir /var/lib/redis
slaveof device1 6379
masterauth arsenal
slave-serve-stale-data yes
slave-read-only yes

slave-priority 100
requirepass arsenal

slave-lazy-flush no
appendonly no
appendfilename "appendonly.aof"
appendfsync everysec
no-appendfsync-on-rewrite no

activerehashing yes

aof-rewrite-incremental-fsync yes
```

I started with the sentinel on `192.168.0.103` with  `redis-server sentinel.conf --sentinel`

```
7951:X 14 Mar 14:19:48.479 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
7951:X 14 Mar 14:19:48.479 # Sentinel ID is 49f552d5540fdcb8aa60be25208c56b689d3c0b0
7951:X 14 Mar 14:19:48.479 # +monitor master mymaster 192.168.0.101 6379 quorum 2

7951:X 14 Mar 14:20:48.480 # +sdown slave 192.168.0.103:6379 192.168.0.103 6379 @ mymaster 192.168.0.101 6379
7951:X 14 Mar 14:21:11.577 # +sdown master mymaster 192.168.0.101 6379
```

My sentinel calling is like this:

```
sentinel = Sentinel([('device3', 26379)], password='arsenal')

sentinel.discover_master('mymaster')

MasterNotFoundError: No master found for 'mymaster'
```

The problem is after I tried to stop the redis-server service on 101, the sentinel can not switch the 103 server as the master.

Anyone who have idea? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In your config `sentinel monitor mymaster 192.168.0.101 6379 2`, quorum is 2, which means only two or more than two Sentinels think master down, can failover start.
2. See [Redis Sentinel doc](https://redis.io/topics/sentinel), only three or more than three Sentinels can be deployed stably, if you only have one Sentinel, it can not elects a leader (which get votes of majority) to start a failover.

Comment: @DennisLi See my "2."，you must have three or more Sentinels to monitor it.